# Can you give me an example of how these assignment operators are used in C?

Tags: c

I'm learning C and came across some very strange assignment operators that I don't understand (Googling them is hard because of the symbols). In order from most to least puzzling:

1. `%=` Modulus Equals
2. `^=` Xor Equals (was he in Star Trek?)
3. `|=` Or Equals

Then I guess `+=`, `-=`, and `*=` which I think I understand but still can't see why they would be used. Could anyone give me some simple examples of how these operators could be useful?

Comment: Just search for C operators, you would get ample for great resoruces. Some good links - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operators-c-c/, http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Comment: `%=` is the emoji for being confused about C operators.

Comment: `why they would be used` to shorten `a = a ^ b` to `a ^= b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Examples:

```
unsigned x;

x ^= (1 << 5); // toggle the 5th bit
//same as
x = x ^ (1 << 5);

x %= 10;  // get the remainder of the x / 10 and save it in x
//same as 
x = x % 10;

x |= (1 << 5); // set the 5th bit
//same as 
x = x | (1 << 5);

x &= ~(1 << 5) // reset the 5th bit
//same as 
x = x & ~(1 << 5);
```

> but still can't see why they would be used

the understanding will come with number of C code lines written.

Answer (score 2):

example of |= is accumulating bits.

```
uint mask = 0;

if (x) mask |= 0x001;
if (y) mask |= 0x02;
....
```

this page is full of ^= https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html